# WPF WVVM: Where/how to create global error messages and program constants?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm writing an app to connect to USB devices using wpf/mvvm, coming from a c/c++ background. What I'd like to do is create global program data such as status/error messages and app related constants.

So for instance, I'm putting the USB connection code in a async Task and then using IProgress to report the status at various checkpoints. Now, we could simply use a magic string for each of these and return it from the Task, but it seems like it would be more efficient to simply return a byte 'statusCode'then use a switch statement or something to display the correct status/error message.

Along those same lines is the app related constants. Say we want our app to be able to be used for multiple devices. Rather than have to make the entire app specific to the device, it would be nice to use abstract variables throughout the app and then somewhere have a single file that lets us tailor the app to a single device.

For instance:

```
DeviceNum = SpecificDeviceNumber;
DeviceName = SpecificDeviceName;
NumOfPorts = ...
```

Then in the program we use them like this:

```
switch(statusCode)
{
    case 1: status = $"Error: We can't connect to the attached "+ DeviceNum + " " + DeviceName + ".  
            Please try again."
    case 2: ...
}
```

In C/C++ we can easily do this by creating a "Device.h" file and everything can be customized using macros (#define). How or what is the best way to implement this in WPF/MVVM?

Comment: Why the downvotes!?

Comment: Hover over the down button: “This question does not show any research effort”. Also, are these messages available in multiple languages?

Comment: @DourHighArch: Thank you! I didn't know about that feature. It's a shame Stack Overflow lets people tell me that I didn't spend 4 days researching this online and in texts before I ask my questions.

Comment: I have same story, I feel you bro. Sadly, your question is a bit wague... But I guess you are very fresh to WPF, that's why. Anyway, you have an answer now, good luck with figuring out how this devil machine works :) When you'll get used to it WPF will be easy.
I hope this question will help others who are coming from C/C++ and are using same keywords as you do.

Comment: Settings or resources can be a good place

Comment: The down-votes are something you have to get over.  People can obviously "know" you didn't do any research.  I get it.  Anyhow, if you don't know about one language specifically, you don't know what to ask for in-that-language.  Hopefully my answer was able to get you at least moving.  Another thing you might get benefit of is using "Generics", but I'm sure you'll come along in time...

Comment: @zORgAlex: Ya, that's the thing, it's hard to ask questions when you don't know what something is called that you're asking about. It's likely that Pavel and DRapps comments are the key...I've yet to see "settings, "resources" or "Generics" so chances are those are the keywords I was missing. I'll happily edit the question to make it more clear for future users if anyone wants to give some critique as to how to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Please excuse the brain-dump, but hopefully it can get you started.  You probably want to get a combination of enumerators for different purposes, but also getting into constants and static values.  Its been a while since I've done C++, but enums can be used for wide variety of things from status codes, allowed choices such as picking to build/generate/steps to do, etc.  They can just be declared and do NOT have to always be 0, 1, 2, 3, etc, but can skip gaps and also be negatives if you want.  If you do NOT explicitly number them and you need to add more in the future and change the order, it could hurt you, especially if some "devices" may have specific hard numeric values.  Explicitly including might be more appropriate.

A next part could be defining some static class that never has to be instantiated, it just exists as long as the "namespace" is included as part of your project (you mentioned having some sort of separate library to hold these pieces.  If so, that MAY create a different namespace... much like System, System.IO, Linq, System.Net, and the many others.

By having a static class, you can define all you want as either "const" or "static".  "const" never change, but give you a readable named reference for readability later in code.  Static means the named reference is always available on the class and it CAN be changed on the object.  Coming from C++, I have to assume you are already familiar with scope of properties as public, private, protected, etc.  Same would apply here.

```
namespace YourConstants
{
    public enum eDeviceStatus
    {
        NotUsed = 0,
        Fail1 = 1,
        SomeOtherFail = 2,
        IsReady = 3,
        etc = 4
    }

    public enum eOtherSettings
    {
        NotSetYet = 0,
        DeviceXMode1 = 1,
        AnotherSetting = 5,
        GapBeforeSomethingElse = 22,
        AndSomeMore = 45
    }

    public static class MyConstants
    {
        public const string Msg1 = "This is a sample message never change";
        public const string OtherMsg = "Some other message to never change";
        public const int SomeNumber = 123;

        public static string CanBeChanged = "Sample Start Message";
        public static int CurrentStatus = 5;

        public static eOtherSettings CurrentSetting = eOtherSettings.NotSetYet;
    }
}
```

Now, IF you were to have the above in some separate library, make sure to add the "using YourConstants;" namespace reference at the top, so all the things declared there will be available.  Then you don't have to EXPLICITLY pre-qualify the references as I have in the code sample below.  This was just to explicitly show that the "namespace YourCommonApp" is some different project that references your other library.  Without the using has no clue of those declarations.

Now, whatever class you are building "Whatever" and have "SomeMethod()", you can reference those things and have readable named context to them.  Also, in this example, since I was doing a case based on an enumerator, the case is forced to match only those explicitly declared.  If you declare to something like and integer and one day have some value of 17, have the corresponding switch case of 17 tested for and does something.  Then, remove 17 from your valid codes, or worse, change it to 23, unless you explicitly renumber the 17 to 23, you have a dead segment of code.  Enums helps eliminate this as a problem.

```
using YourConstants;

namespace YourCommonApp
{
    public class Whatever
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            switch(YourConstants.MyConstants.CurrentSetting)
            {
                case YourConstants.eOtherSettings.NotSetYet:
                    MessageBox.Show(YourConstants.MyConstants.Msg1);
                    break;

                case YourConstants.eOtherSettings.DeviceXMode1:
                    MessageBox.Show(YourConstants.MyConstants.OtherMsg);
                    break;

                default:
                    // change or do something on your single-instance main static class
                    YourConstants.MyConstants.CurrentSetting = YourConstants.eOtherSettings.AnotherSetting;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, since you are learning for WPF, hopefully this will get you going with whatever you are developing.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for putting so much time into this for me! This will definitely help a bunch. Ya, the thing is you can easily find beginner and really advanced tutorials, but there tends to be a gap in middle showing practical best practices. For instance, a pro is likely always going to set up a project a certain way, say creating View, ViewModel, Model, Images and Commands folders, Styles and Animations xaml files, and a BaseViewModel class to implement INotifyPC and other interfaces. Without this info, when a noob like me tries to do anything practical, it turns into a mess fast.

Comment: @liquidair, glad to help.  I too had a mind-numbing beginning in WPF, data binding and such.  Also note, when you get INTO it, you can do binding to static class/values as well so you don't have to always create properties on many objects that all point to the static.  You can bind to static references...